# Print list with flush

Tags: python

I want to print a list, perform some operations and print again, flushing the list.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range (0, 10):
    a.append(i)
    a=a[-5:]
    print(*a, sep='\n')
```

I expect the list to be cleared from the screen and the new one takes its place, buy I don't know how to to that.

Comment: Your formatting seems to be odd. But, issue seems to be related to the immutable nature of the lists. If you want to have a list with new values while keeping the old ones then create a new list from your existing list.

Comment: Clearing the screen isn't something that can be universally done in the terminal. You can use `os.system('clear')`, or some VT100 codes to move the cursor up to the start of the list again, but it's not going to be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the `colorama` package to enable ANSI escape sequences:

```
import colorama
import time
colorama.init()

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range (0, 10):
    a.append(i)
    a=a[-5:]
    print(*a, end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

The `'\r'` character places the cursor back at the beginning of the line, so you can "print over it".

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point, try this:

```
import sys
import time

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range (0, 10):
  a.append(i)
  a=a[-5:]
  print(chr(27) + "[2J")
  print(*a, sep='\n', flush=True)
  time.sleep(0.5)
```